# how fix design issue when left navbar is overcollapse

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

In my page I am using Left navbar, So when I expand and collapse the navbar, one the `div` width getting changed. Due to that change the entire design getting change.

When Navbar is collapsed
[image: When Navbar is collapsed]

When Navbar is Expand

It is working perfectly when the left navbar is Expand.
[image]

So I want to keep the background width should same when the navbar expands or collapse.

Answer (score 0):

Please reread your question and add more information and apply proper english please. Do you seek a solution with javascript or pure css?

Does the navbar collapse because of css media queries? 
In that case you could use the following `.scss` solution to apply background property changes according to your screensize:

```
$widthMedium: /*apply amount of pixels of media query of collapsable nav*/ px;

@mixin on-max-widthMedium {
  /* Do max-width for a behavior on a width below a certain limit */
  @media (max-width:$widthMedium) {
    @content;
  }
}

.classYouWantToChangeWhenNavBarIsNotCollapsed {
  @include on-max-widthMedium { 
     // For example:
     background-size: contain;
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm seeking a solution with pure css

Comment: Is it possible to fix the issue by adding inline css?

Comment: You need to apply a width to your div class which has the same condition as your collapsable navbar in my opinion.